# Is it possible to limit the number of results returned by ImailFolder.Search()?

Tags: mailkit, mimekit

While there are many ways of searching for uniqueid's in a mail folder, I can't find a way to limiting the number of results that are returned by a mistakenly open-ended query.

```
    private SearchQuery  CreateSearchQuery(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
    {
        var startDateQuery = SearchQuery.DeliveredAfter(start.Value); 
        var endDateQuery = SearchQuery.DeliveredBefore(end.Value);
        return new MailKit.Search.BinarySearchQuery(SearchTerm.And, startDateQuery, endDateQuery);
    }


    var searchByDateQuery = CreateSearchQuery(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MaxValue);
    resultSet = theFolder.Search(searchByDateQuery) ?? new List<UniqueId>();
```

Is there a way of adding a search term that says, give me the first 100 items that match this date query?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to limit the results since the IMAP protocol does not provide the means to do so. As an aside, the `Search()` method should never return `null`, so it's unnecessary to do `?? new List<UniqueId> ()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jeffrey says, there is no solution.